# Toggle Icon value in Iteration

Tags: aura

I have a table that I'm generating using `aura:iteration`. And the code is as below.

```
<aura:attribute name="icon" type="String" default="utility:down"/>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.careerData}" var="note">
        <tr>
            <td data-id="{!note.id}" > 
                <div class="slds-truncate clist1" data-id="{!note.id}" >
                    {!note.noteText}
                </div>
                <div> <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="{!v.icon}" variant="bare" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" alternativeText="Settings" title="Settings" /></div>
            </td>
            <td>{!note.contactedByType}</td>
        </tr>
    </aura:iteration>
```

here In my `handleClick`, I want to toggle the icon of only the clicked `buttonIcon`

when I'm trying to use the below `js`, it is toggling all the icons.

```
handleClick: function(c,e){
        c.set("v.icon", c.get("v.icon")=="utility:down"? "utility:up":"utility:down");
}
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is to change the value of the `v.icon` attribute. That change will apply to all the places in which you're using it (all the buttons).

What you can do instead, is to get the button element that was clicked, and change its `iconName`:

```
({
    handleClick: function(c,e){
        var clickedButton = e.getSource();
        var currentIconName = clickedButton.get("v.iconName");
        var nameToSet = currentIconName === "utility:down"? "utility:up":"utility:down"
        clickedButton.set("v.iconName", nameToSet);
    }
})
```

Indeed you don't need the `v.icon` attribute. You can just initialize the iconName to "utility:down", and then change it when clicked.

Comment: Thanks, buddy. You are a lifesaver :-)